# c struct member array of struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct, member

I have those two struct

```
struct List {
    unsigned length;
    char * value;
};

struct bal {
    List name;              
    List ** attributes;     
};
```

So struct List will handle a string, im adding char by char (with a function using malloc) to create my string.

My struct bal as two members, one it's the name which is a struct List and the other member is an Array of Struct List, so i can add attributes to a struct bal.

I've no problem until im trying to access my list of attributes of a struct bal. If my struct bal as 3 attributes, the representation of my list of attributes  should be like this :

```
attributes[0];
attributes[1];
attributes[2];
```

Each position is a struct List. so if i want to let say printf an attribute, my thinking is thats i've to do something like :

```
bal firstBal;
```

Let say i've add 3 attributes within the program.

And then to print it i've to do :

```
printf( "The first attributes is : %s ", firstBal->attributes[0]->value);
```

But when i do this, i get the error :

```
error: request for member value in something not a structure or union
```

But i dont get why ? my struct bal have a member which is an Array of struct List, so when im adding a struct List in that array, i should be able to access the member Value of my struct List.

The member value of my struct List is a string so ...

Thank you very much !

Comment: I think you need to post the part with malloc().

Comment: You haven't shown you you allocate your structures. There's no way to answer some of the questions without that information.  Also, you declared `bal firstBal` indicating `firstBal` as a `struct`, but then you reference it as a pointer: `firstBal->...`. You should reference it as: `firstBal.attributes[0]->value` since it's not a pointer. The `->` operator is for *pointer* to structure (*e.g.*, if you had the declaration `bal *firstBal;` and you dynamically allocated `firstBal`).

Answer (score 0):

I identify two issues with your code:

1. You mention that in `struct bal`

   > the other member is an Array of `struct List`

   However, member `attributes` is declared in your code as `List **`, i.e. as a pointer to an array of `List` variables and my guess is that this is not what you wanted.
2. The `->` operator is used for accessing members of a struct/union **pointed by** a pointer variable (this is the reason why it looks this an arrow). However, in your code this is not the case as `firstBal` is not defined as a pointer but just as a variable of type `struct bal`. Therefore, in order to use its member fields you should use the `.` operator rather than the `->` operator (i.e. `firatBal.attributes`).

   Now, the type of `firstBal->attributes[0]` is dependent on what you want. If you stick with having attributes to be of type `List **` then it is ok. However, per my comment above, assuming that the right type for it is `List *` then using the array access operator (`[]`) would already provide you the variable rather than a pointer to it. In other words `firstBal->attributes[0]` would be of type `List` and NOT `List *`, which means that you cannot use the `->` operator to access its members but should use the `.` operator

Answer (score 0):

You need a declaration:

```
struct List attributes[3];
```

And its pointer should be ***pattributes**

With **pattributes = &attributes[0];** following.